# How many combination exist in this situation?

Tags: combinatorics

There are $h$ groups of different elements each has a different size:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\text{Group 1}: ~~~~a_{11}& a_{12} & ... & a_{1k_1} & \\
\text{Group 2}:~~~~a_{21}& a_{22} &  ...& a_{2k_2} \\
\vdots&&&\\
\text{Group h}:~~~~a_{h1}& a_{h2} & ... & a_{hk_h} & \\
\end{matrix} 
$$

From each group, we can choose at most one element. I like to know how many combinations we can create when the order is not important.

If the length is **1**, the answer is $\sum_{i=1}^{h}k_i$. If the length is **2**, I think the answer is $$(\sum_{i=1}^{h}k_i)^{2} - \sum_{i=1}^{h}k_i^2$$

but I can not do the math when the length of the combination is larger. Can any body help me?

Thanks

Comment: If $l$ is the length, then the number of combinations is:
$$
    \sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<...<i_l\leq h} k_{i_1}k_{i_2}...k_{i_l}
$$
if that helps.

Comment: If order is unimportant, for the length 2 case you are off by a factor of two.

Comment: Also, @zuggg's answer is given in terms of the [elementary symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial). It appears from the question you may prefer them in terms of [power-sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial) ones. Thankfully, [Newton has told us how to convert from one to the other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

Comment: Thanks to you two and Newton. @zuggg, I 'd like to mark yours as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $l$ is the length, then the number of combinations is:
$$
 \sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<...<i_l\leq h} k_{i_1}k_{i_2}\dots k_{i_l}
$$
See also Willie Wong's comment for an alternate way of writing that sum.